# OutofMemory error with ibm jdk 1.7

Tags: out-of-memory, ibm-jdk

I am using IBM jdk 1.7(to support TLS cyphers) for an struts based application deployed with embedded tomcat.
We are running with memory leaks(OOM) that generated almost 30 gigs of dumps.This has become a rotine event.
We have tried increasing the heap mem by including
wrapper.java.additional.1="-XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xss2048k" in the wrapper.conf.
But this didnt help much.

Comment: 1. Could you paste an exception stacktrace? 2. Did you try to analyze thread dump heap regarding to objects on heap? That type (memory leaks) of problems are not easy to investigate so you have to deep analyze your system .

Answer (score 0):

Try using Memory Analyzer, you can follow the instructions here to download and install it:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/tools/memoryanalyzer/

It should provide an overview of your heap usage.
I'd recommend starting with the dominator tree view to see which objects are responsible for keeping data alive on the heap. You can also run various reports which analyse the heap for you.

You should have core files (.dmp) and heap dumps (.phd), the core files will be large but may be faster to access and will also contain all the values for basic types in objects and strings. The phd files just contain object sizes and the connections between them. It may be easier to relate what you are seeing back to your code if you start with the core file.